# Iterate through elements and retrieve text values

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

I have a small scraping program, that decides how many times to loop correctly

I have three values i want extracted. "// GET THREE VALUES"

I want to put a counter on them , so each loop will get the value for each loop.

Looking for a better way of doing it , currently it only gets first value over and over... until end of loop.

````
package scraping;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class scrape {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

    }

    @Test
    public void writeexcel() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get(
                "https://www.thephonebook.bt.com/Business/TypeSearch/?BusinessSearchTerm=farmers&Location=Bedford%20%20(Bedfordshire)&PageNumber=1&LocationFound=true");

        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'black medium pr-4')]"));

        for (int i = 1; i < 26; i = i + 2) {

            System.out.println("count = " + i);

                // GET THREE VALUES
    
            WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'black medium pr-4')]"));
            String Nameval = name.getAttribute("innerHTML");

            WebElement Add1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'description truncatePL linktooltipAddressListing')]"));
            String Add1val = Add1.getAttribute("innerHTML");
            
            WebElement Tel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-ref,'phone number')]"));
            String Telval = Tel.getAttribute("innerHTML");


            System.out.println(Nameval + " , " + Add1val + " , " + Telval);

        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}```
````

Comment: Makes sense driver.find returns the first xpath with those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a specific node index for your target starting from one

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i = i + 2) {

        System.out.println("count = " + i);

            // GET THREE VALUES

        WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[contains(@class,'black medium pr-4')])[" + i + "]"));
        String Nameval = name.getAttribute("innerHTML");

        WebElement Add1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'description truncatePL linktooltipAddressListing')])[" + i + "]"));
        String Add1val = Add1.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        
        WebElement Tel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@data-ref,'phone number')])[" + i + "]"));
        String Telval = Tel.getAttribute("innerHTML");


        System.out.println(Nameval + " , " + Add1val + " , " + Telval);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list you found before the loop (and finding the other two lists).

```
List<WebElement> nameElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'black medium pr-4')]"));
List<WebElement> Add1Elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'description truncatePL linktooltipAddressListing')]"));
List<WebElement> TelElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-ref,'phone number')]"));

for (int i = 1; i < 26; i = i + 2) {
    System.out.println("count = " + i);

    // GET THREE VALUES

    String Nameval = nameElements[i].getAttribute("innerHTML");

    String Add1val = Add1Elements[i].getAttribute("innerHTML");

    String Telval = TelElements[i].getAttribute("innerHTML");

    System.out.println(Nameval + " , " + Add1val + " , " + Telval);
}
```